# Will I still have the use of my cold water while my water heater is disconnected for renovations?

Tags: water, water-heater

I am having the floorcovering replaced in the laundry room, where my water heater is located. When the plumber temporarily removes the water heater, will I still have use of the cold water throughout the home, until the plumber reinstalls the water heater? It may be a day or two. Thanks!

Comment: Should have.  Most hot water heaters get their cold water from a tee with a shut off valve.

Comment: If the valves isolating the water heater are correct, yes. If the valves are not correct or not there at all, no.

Comment: That depends on whether the shutoff valves are present to successfully do that.  Note George Anderson's comment that many valves when open  *will backflow* cold water up their hot line, and you could have a flood in the laundry room if that is not closed off with a valve or capped off.

Comment: When the plumber temporarily removes the water heater, will I still have use of the cold water throughout the home, until the plumber reinstalls the water heater? That's correct. You only get hot water via hot water heater tank or tankless

Answer (score 18):

If the plumber does their work correctly, yes.

Typically, there should be a shut-off valve just for the water heater. They would turn off water to the water heater, then work on it (after capping the hot water line). You would only lose hot water to the house.

Even if there's not, then a competent plumber would install one. That's a 15-minute job. Then you would still get cold water during the works.

Comment: One thing to be careful about is the hot water line from the water heater should be capped when the WH is removed.  Mixing valves on sinks, etc. can backflow cold water into the HW pipe and then it comes out at the WH making a mess.  Turning the valve to full cold should prevent that, but that's easy to forget.  A simple cap installed on the HW line is good insurance.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson This should be the answer. IF the hot water side isn't capped, then I would bet 100% that someone in the house will mix the cold water into the hot side at another fixture.

Comment: @RibaldEddie edited to add this detail. It wouldn't have crossed my mind that a plumber would not think of capping the hot water line. But yeah, this is DIY, and it could guide the next DIY'er to not forget this step.

Comment: Mine has a valve on the inlet and outlet so closing them will isolate the system. You could always connect the pipe feeding the hot water heater to the pipe that is connected to the outlet of the hot water if that is easier.

Comment: Note that while installing a shutoff valve is a 15-minute job for a plumber, in my area plumbers charge $200+ to do this - even while replacing the water heater :o

Comment: May still be a good investment against the next time a water heater reaches end of life.